# AutoStart application on BOOT_COMPLTED unable to start service Intent not found

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create a Service application without a UI/Activity.
The service will start on BOOT_COMPLETED. Currently I am experiencing an issue when the receiver service cannot start the main service.

The error sound like that (Android Device Monitor):

Tag: Activity Manager
Text: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.remote.cat/.ActionService } U=0: not found

My android OS version on the device is 4.2.2

I am testing it via this command in PowerShell:

```
adb.exe shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.remote.cat/.AutoStartServiceReceiver
```

Both services are in the root of the package **com.remote.cat**

Feel like I am missing a small thing or having a typo, would greatly appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Here is the code of the manifest:

```
    <manifest   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.remote.cat"
            android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name="com.remote.cat.AutoStartServiceReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <service android:name="com.remote.cat.AutoStartServiceReceiver"></service>
    <service android:name="com.remote.cat.ActionService"></service>

</manifest>
```

Here is the brodcastreceiver class:

```
package com.remote.cat;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ActionService.class);
            //Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.remote.cat.ActionService");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main service that I am trying to start:

```
package com.remote.cat;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ActionService extends Service
{
    private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(4);

        final ScheduledFuture<?> handle = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one minute message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, 0, 8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AutoStartServiceReceiver` declaration in the manifest to be a `<receiver>` rather than `<service>`.

Comment: this is a service declaration. I do believe it should be <service>. Well, I have tried it anyway. Did not helped... :(
the receiver declaration is in <application> tag above.

Comment: In addition to having the receiver declared as such on the manifest (not a service), your app must also be started by the user manually the first time. Until that happens, the system considers the app disabled and won't deliver boot completed. After the use starts your app's main activity once, it will start delivering the broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your broadcastreceiver class

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
```

it should be

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
```

**EDIT**

I believe you have to declare your services inside the application tag since it is a part of the application

Comment: both of them are correct:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED